# Weird change in clang diagnostics with c++17

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

So in general this is more of a theoretical language lawyer question, than an actual one. While fighting with template with obscure template error, I found a behavior I could not explain with clang (bottom line - no warning that I am trying to move a class that is not movable). The weird thing is that the behaviour with clang changes depending on whether `-std=c++17` is present or not.

So here is the MVP of the issue:

```
#include <utility>

struct INoLikeToMoveIt
{
    INoLikeToMoveIt() = default;
    INoLikeToMoveIt(const INoLikeToMoveIt&) = delete;
    INoLikeToMoveIt(INoLikeToMoveIt&&) = delete;
    INoLikeToMoveIt& operator=(const INoLikeToMoveIt&) = delete;
    INoLikeToMoveIt& operator=(INoLikeToMoveIt&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    INoLikeToMoveIt a, b;
    auto c = std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this will not work (but since in the actual case the non movable class was a member of a parent class hidden deep in the sources, w/o any warnings that it is not movable I could not immediately understand what is going on). So taking this example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ki-sUh) with `-std=c+=17` gives:

```
n file included from <source>:1:

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/utility:70:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:529:14: error: no matching constructor for initialization of '__pair_type' (aka 'pair<INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>')

      return __pair_type(std::forward<_T1>(__x), std::forward<_T2>(__y));

             ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:15:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_pair<INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>' requested here

    auto c = std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b));

                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:260:17: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_ConstructiblePair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt, _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

      constexpr pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)

                ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:269:26: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_ConstructiblePair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt, _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

      explicit constexpr pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)

                         ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:311:18: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_MoveCopyPair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

       constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)

                 ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:318:27: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_MoveCopyPair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

       explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)

                          ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:325:18: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_CopyMovePair()' was not satisfied [with _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

       constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)

                 ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:332:17: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_CopyMovePair()' was not satisfied [with _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

       explicit pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)

                ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:341:12: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_MoveConstructiblePair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt, _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

        constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)

                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:350:21: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_PCC<true, INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>::_MoveConstructiblePair()' was not satisfied [with _U1 = INoLikeToMoveIt, _U2 = INoLikeToMoveIt]

        explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)

                           ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:229:26: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided

      _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair()

                         ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:242:26: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided

      explicit constexpr pair()

                         ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:291:19: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__p', but 2 arguments were provided

        constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)

                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:300:21: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__p', but 2 arguments were provided

        explicit constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)

                           ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:360:12: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__p', but 2 arguments were provided

        constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)

                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:370:21: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__p', but 2 arguments were provided

        explicit constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)

                           ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:375:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided

        pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);

        ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 2 were provided

        pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,

        ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided

      constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;

                ^

1 error generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

which I would interpret as "hey I'm gonna tell you why you can't all the stuff you actually don't want, but not that the move ctor is deleted". Once I change `-std=c++14` the same diagnostic but with a trailing lines:

```
<source>:15:10: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::pair<INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>'

    auto c = std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b));

         ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here

      constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;

                ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:214:11: note: copy constructor of 'pair<INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>' is implicitly deleted because field 'first' has a deleted copy constructor

      _T1 first;                 /// @c first is a copy of the first object

          ^

<source>:6:5: note: 'INoLikeToMoveIt' has been explicitly marked deleted here

    INoLikeToMoveIt(const INoLikeToMoveIt&) = delete;
    ^

2 errors generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

which is still does not mention the deleted move c-tor, but at least points me to culprit. Initially I though, hey, maybe there is a new overload/semantics for `std::make_pair` that would cause this, but looking at [std::make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) does not show any C++17 relevant changes. So is this just a weird behaviour in diagnostics or is there an explanation for this? Just curios.

Comment: I'm going to chalk this up to just changes in C++17 changed how clang does its template error handling.  FWIW, in the C++17 message the second line is *<source>:15:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_pair<INoLikeToMoveIt, INoLikeToMoveIt>' requested here

    auto c = std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b));* which at least tells you there is somrthing wrong trying to move `a` and `b` into the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver yep, in my case the issue was that as I mentioned the non movable thing was a member of one of the base class of the type that I was moving, so it was not evident. But yeah, when I found the pair ctor that I needed and saw `is_nothrow_constructible` and ran that on my type, it explained stuff. But I was just wondering that I was handed virtually all the info I did not need, but no the info on the overload that I needed. I mean smth like `is_nothrow_constructible` failed or similar, would have solved it.